# Is the offset parameter of FileStream.Read zero-based?

Tags: c#, filestream

The second parameter of the FileStream.Read method is called offset but is it zero-based like an index or does it start from one?

Comment: Why on earth would it start at 1??  :)

Comment: You seem to imply that you think that the term *index* refers to zero-based numbering, while the term *offset* refers to something else. This is not the case — the two terms are often used interchangeably.

Comment: According to wikipedia, an offset is the distance of one element from another in an array.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(computer_science)
In other words it is the number of positions and when counting the number of positions it is only natural to start counting from one and not zero. That is why I thought it possibly started at one and not from zero. From what I have read on that wikipedia page it sounds as if offset and index are not to be used interchangeably as you suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It starts from zero indicating the beginning of the stream. Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx):

> offset
>
> The
>   **zero-based** byte offset in buffer at
>   which to begin storing the data read
>   from the current stream.from the current stream.